# navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia permission denied

Tags: javascript

I am trying to navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia to select a camera from a dropdown and use it, here is my code that gets my devices:

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');

    navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(function (devices) {
        for (var i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
            var device = devices[i];
            if (device.kind === 'videoinput') {
                var option = document.createElement('option');
                option.value = device.deviceId;
                option.text = device.label || 'camera ' + (i + 1);
                document.querySelector('select#videoSource').appendChild(option);
            }
        };
    });
```

and here is my on change code to use the camera:

```
$("#videoSource").on("change", function () {

        var x = $(this).value;
        var constraints = { deviceId: { exact: x } };

        if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {

            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: constraints }).then(function (stream) {
                video.srcObject = stream;
                video.play();
            });

        }

    });
```

When I goto select an option to use a camera I get this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Permission denied

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have test your code in Stackblitz and it works for me!

[JQuery Camera](https://stackblitz.com/edit/jquery-video-camera)

For triggering the change event in the select, I have added an extra option for selection.

Maybe your problem is that you have denied the permissions.

Comment: You're right I did....In my dropdown I have two cameras and no matter which one I select it also goes to the first one, what am I doing wrong there?

Comment: Ahh if you have two cameras you can trigger the change event. For me the code seems to be ok as stackblitz example demonstrates. Could you try to reset the permissions of the camera? In Chrome you can do it as is described [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/114662?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en-GB)